# Adding card images into a card game rather than text using arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, playing-cards

My program keeps crashing it's a blackjack/21 game (I'm not sure of the difference) the program asks the player what they would like to do and then once they have chosen stick it crashes I've checked the console and no errors are appearing and I've tested the javascript in repl and it works fine just not when I try to incorporate it into a html page.

Also when it does work it will only show the house cards or the second players cards not all players cards.

Finally once this is working I would like to improve it by adding in images of the cards for the user but I have no idea how to start.

```
<html>
<head>
<h1 align="center">21 Game</h1>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#458B00">

<div align='center'>
    <h3>House Cards</h3>
    <h5 id='housecurrenthand'></h5>
    <h5 id='househand'> </h5>

    <h3>Players Cards</h3>
    <h5 id='playershand1'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand2'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand3'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand4'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand5'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand6'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand7'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand8'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand9'> </h5>
    <h5 id='playershand10'> </h5>

    <h4 id='winner'> </h4>

    <button onclick="play()" float='bottom'>Play</button>

</div>
<script language='JavaScript'> 

function play() {
  playersQ = prompt('How many people are playing?');
  playershands = [];
  i = 0;
  count = 0;
  var player_cards = 0;

  function player() {
    var player_cards = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 1;
    while (player_cards < 21) {
      Hit = prompt('Players cards are ' + player_cards + ' Would you like stick or twist?(S/T)')
      if (Hit == 'T') {
        player_cards = player_cards + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
      } else if (Hit == 'S') {
        break;
      } else if (player_cards > 21) {
        alert('Player is bust');
        break;
      }
    }
    return player_cards;
  }

  function house() {
    var house_cards = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 1;
    while (house_cards < 18 && house_cards < 22) {
      house_cards = house_cards + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    }
    return house_cards;
  }

  while (i < playersQ) {
    playershands.push(player());
    i = i + 1;
  }

var house_hand = house();



  while (count < playersQ) {
    count2 = count + 1
    document.getElementById('playershand' +i ).innerHTML = ('Player ' + count2 + ' has ' + playershands[count]);
  }

document.getElementById('househand').innerHTML = ('House has ' + house_hand);

count = 0 ;

while (count < playersQ){
    if (playershands[count] > house_hand && playershands[count] < 22) {
      document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = ('Player wins');
      count = count + 1;
    } else if (house_hand > playershands[count] && house_hand < 22) {
      document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = ('House wins');
      break;
    } else if (house_hand == playershands[count]) {
      document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = ('draw');
      break;
    }
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, if the program crashes, you must have some idea of why - an error, an exception, ...? Secondly, but this relates only to the player experience, it would technically be possible to have a handful of aces with your program.

Comment: It works for me. By the way, this shouldn't be a problem in a non-strict mode, but you forgot to declare your `Hit` variable.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a card you can :

- Draw them in a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)
- tell that card "Ace of heart" A♥ equals to "1A.png"
- May it is possoble ton generate cards using [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)

Have a nice dev !